# How do I replace a word without putting the word into a register?

Tags: replace, register

Right now I press `ce` to replace a word. However, this overrides anything that was in my register before. How can I replace a word and go into insert mode after without replacing what was in my register previously?

Comment: Side note: `ciw` has benefits over `ce`. Read the text objects help for more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the black hole register (see [`:h quote_`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#quote_)):

> When writing to this register, nothing happens.  This can be used to delete
>   text without affecting the normal registers.  When reading from this register,
>   nothing is returned.

Simply do `"_ce` so that the deleted text will be put into the black hole register and not into your unnamed register.

Comment: Thanks a lot,  just as a follow up if I wanted to remap `ce` to do this by default would this work:                                                                                         


`nnoremap ce "_ce`

Comment: Why not try it yourself and see?

Comment: @InKnight (BLayer makes a really good point) Yes it should work but I think that would be extremely inconvenient and you'd need to make sure that `ttimeout` and `ttimeoutlen` are set properly. I don't recommend such a mapping.

Answer (score 0):

@statox is spot on with the *Black hole* register.

In fact I use this so much I remapped to my `x` key in my .vimrc file:
    `noremap x "_x`  This allows me to visual select then `x` it away while maintaining my last yanked text.

If you want to swap text from one place to another check out [tommcdo/vim-exchange](https://github.com/tommcdo/vim-exchange).

Comment: `x` is such a common command that remapping it systematically doesn't seem like a good idea (let say I mistype `lsit` instead of `list` I can't do `xp` anymore to invert the `s` and the `i`). Also if you use it only for visally selected text you should use a mode specific mapping like `vnoremap`

Comment: I hadn't used `xp` before for swapping letter, thank you (had to use `Xp` to work with my current mapping). The `vnoremap` would reduce how much it changes the underlining functionality. In the end, Vim becomes a custom editor based on the .vimrc you have.